# Why do I get this unexpected result using atoi() in C?

Tags: c, atoi

I don't understand the results of the following C code.

```
main()
{
    char s[] = "AAA";
    advanceString(s);
}

void advanceString(p[3])
{
    int val = atoi(p);
    printf("The atoi val is %d\n",val);
}
```

Here the `atoi` value is shown as 0, but I could not figure out the exact reason.
As per my understanding, it should be the summation of decimal equivalent of each values in the array? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please paste actual code that compiles.

Comment: @Marcelo Does that really matter in this case?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. But is it really that hard, given that the OP has already seen the result of running the program?

Comment: Why doesnt it convert the decimel equivalent of the ascii values(alphabets)?

Comment: @maddy, because that's not what `atoi()` is meant to do.

Comment: I guess so,i am supposed to use strtol.

Comment: @maddy `strtol` won't do what you're describing either.  No standard library function will; it's not something people normally do.

Comment: What has become of the tradition of reading the fine manual?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I assume about the behaviour of atoi() on error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393162/what-can-i-assume-about-the-behaviour-of-atoi-on-error)

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 53):

[`atoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) converts a string representation of an integer into its value. It will not convert arbitrary characters into their decimal value. For instance:

```
int main(void)
{
    const char *string="12345";

    printf("The value of %s is %d\n", string, atoi(string));

    return 0;
}
```

There's nothing in the standard C library that will convert "A" to 65 or "Z" to 90, you'd need to write that yourself, specifically for whatever charset you're expecting as input.

Now that you know what `atoi()` does, ***please don't use it*** to deal with numeric input in whatever you come up with. You really should deal with input not being what you expect. *Hmm, what happens when I enter 65 instead of A?* Teachers love to break things.

`atoi()` doesn't do any error checking whatsoever, which makes anything relying on it to convert arbitrary input fragile, at best. Instead, use [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) (POSIX centric example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    static const char *input ="123abc";
    char *garbage = NULL;
    long value = 0;

    errno = 0;

    value = strtol(input, &garbage, 0);

    switch (errno) {
        case ERANGE:
            printf("The data could not be represented.\n");
            return 1;
        // host-specific (GNU/Linux in my case)
        case EINVAL:
            printf("Unsupported base / radix.\n");
            return 1;
    }

    printf("The value is %ld, leftover garbage in the string is %s\n",
           // Again, host-specific, avoid trying to print NULL.
           value, garbage == NULL ? "N/A" : garbage);

    return 0;
}
```

When run, this gives:

> The value is 123, leftover garbage in
>   the string is abc

If you don't care about saving / examining the garbage, you can set the second argument to `NULL`. There is no need to `free(garbage)`. Also note, if you pass 0 as the third argument, it's assumed the input is the desired value of a decimal, hex or octal representation. If you need a radix of 10, use 10 - it will fail if the input is not as you expect.

You'd also check the return value for the maximum and minimum value a `long int` can handle. However, if either are returned to indicate an error, `errno` is set. An exercise for the reader is to change `*input` from `123abc` to `abc123`.

It's important to check the return, as your example shows what happens if you don't. AbcDeFg is not a string representation of an integer, and you need to deal with that in your function.

For your implementation, the most basic advice I can give you would be a series of switches, something like:

```
// signed, since a return value of 0 is acceptable (NULL), -1
// means failure
int ascii_to_ascii_val(const char *in)
{
    switch(in) {
        // 64 other cases before 'A'
        case 'A':
           return 65;
        // keep going from here
        default:
            return -1; // failure

}
```

.. then just run that in a loop.

Or, pre-populate a dictionary that a lookup function could scope (better). You wouldn't need hashes, just a key -> value store since you know what it's going to contain in advance, where the standard ASCII characters are keys, and their corresponding identifiers are values.

Comment: You can use the [strerror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strerror) to get a human readable text from an error code.

Comment: while the answer is correct it would be helping more if the answer would tell the OP on how to solve his problem.

Comment: @Alex Believe it or not, I just saw your comment. Edited a bit :)

Comment: The `garbage == NULL` tests appears unnecessary.  I see no specified result of `strtol()` that would result in `garbage == NULL`.  FWIW `EINVAL` is not in the C spec.

Comment: @chux Does appear to be GNU/Linux specific. Comment added.

Answer (score 12):

It tries to convert the string into an integer. Since AAA cannot be converted into an integer the value is 0. Try giving it 42 or something.

> If no valid conversion could be
>   performed, a zero value is returned.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Answer (score 6):

Read `atoi()` as a to i (ASCII to integer).

`atoi()` converts a string representing a decimal number, to integer.

```
char s[] = "42";
int num = atoi(s); //The value of num is 42.
```

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` expects its argument to be a string representation of a decimal (base-10) integer constant; `AAA` is not a valid decimal integer constant, so `atoi` returns 0 because it has no other way to indicate that the input is invalid.

Note that `atoi` will convert up to the first character that isn't part of a valid integer constant; in other words, "123" and "123w" will both be converted to 123.

Like everyone else is saying, don't use `atoi`; use `strtol` instead.