# Convert char * to short and char

Tags: c

char * x="a";
how would i convert it to char y='a';

also if i have a short char * a="100"
how can i convert it to short b=100

thanks

Comment: If your question has been answered and you have another question, accept the answer here and ask your next question as a new question.

Comment: What in the world is `short char`?

Comment: By the way you should probably never use the `short` type unless you have a really good reason. It's likely to be slow and has no benefits unless you're making a huge array of numbers that all fit in `short`, but then it would probably be better to use a specific-size type like `int16_t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char * x = "a";
char y = *x; //or x[0]


char * a = "100";
short b = atoi(a);
```

Note that assigning return value of `atoi` to a short might lead to overflow.

Also read why [strtol is preferred over atoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729460/usage-of-atoi-in-the-c-language/2729534#2729534) for string to number conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's all you wanted to do and didn't care about error checking:

```
char y= *x;
short b= atoi(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

- A char * can be used as an array of chars. To get the first letter, use `char y = x[0]`
- A string can be converted to a number using the function [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi)