# How do you cast a char* to an int or a double in C

Tags: c

Sorry if this is a super easy question, but I am very new to C. I want to be able to cast char*s into doubles and ints and can't seem to find an explanation as to how.

Edit:
I am reading in user input, which is a char*. Half of the input I want to convert from, say, "23" to 23 and half from, for example, "23.4" to 23.4.

Comment: Do you mean cast or convert?  In other words do you want to convert `"42"` into the number `42` or treat the memory the `char*` points to as an `int`

Comment: Working code on how to use `strtol()` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2729534/50049), I'm closing this out as too localized since you weren't quite sure of the problem you were facing.

Answer (score 25):

You can *cast* a `char*` like this:

```
char  *c = "123.45";
int    i = (int) c;      // cast to int
double d = (double) c;   // cast to double
```

But that will give nonsensical results. It just coerces the pointer to be treated as an integer or double.

I presume what you want is to *parse* (rather than cast) the text into an `int` or `double`. Try this:

```
char  *c = "123.45";
int    i = atoi(c);
double d = atof(c);
```

Comment: (speaking just as a user here, not a mod) `atoi()` is not safe.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you can do this: (int)pointer.

However, you are probably looking for the atoi and atof functions.

atoi is a function that converts a char* pointing to a string containing an integer in decimal to an integer .

atof is likewise for double.

Comment: The `strtol()` family of functions is recommended over `atoi()`, if only because `atoi()` returns the same thing when it fails and when it successfully parses `0`.

Comment: `atoi()` does no error checking whatsoever. `strtol()` does handle errors, sets meaningful errnos and even copies garbage found in input for later inspection.

Comment: True, but atoi is closer to the equivalent of cast string to integer in higher level languages.