# Type Casting from char * to int

Tags: c, type-conversion

How can I store the value pointed by the char pointer into an integer variable? I have the following code:

```
main ()
{
  int i;
  char *tmp = "10";
  i = (int)tmp;
  printf("value of i is %d",i);
}
```

Is my code most efficient for the given task? I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: What language? C? C++? C#?

Answer (score 3):

A string in C is just an array of characters, and `tmp` points to the first character in the string. Your code converts this pointer value (a memory address) to an integer and stores it in `i`.

What you really want to do is use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) in stdlib:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
main ()
{
  int i;
  char *tmp = "10";
  i = (int) strtol(tmp, 0, 10);
  printf("value of i is %d",i);
}
```

Comment: Just a note, his code does not convert the first char, but stores the address of the first char array in i.

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually here the value of tmp is unknown, because i am reading the value of tmp from another file in that case i cannot use strtol right?

Comment: Of course you can, as long as you are aware that if `tmp` doesn't start with a number then `strtol` will return `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) for string to int conversions.

Note that [atoi does no error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729460/why-do-i-get-this-unexpected-result-using-atoi-in-c) so only use it if you know exactly what your input is (like the constant string you have in your example). Otherwise use Emil Vikström's answer.